# How to reuse type come from generic?

Tags: typescript

For example I have STRING type and reuse it in both function test, test2 which is in test.

So I coded like this:

```
type STRING = string

const test = <A = STRING>() => {
  test2<A>("0")
}

const test2 = <B>(b: B) => {
  console.log(b)
}

console.log(test())
```

Than it complains me `'A' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '"0"'.`

I want to reuse STRING type, but solve this issue how to??

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shaw-i6xbu?file=/src/index.ts:205-225

Comment: `A` can be anything but you pass a `string` to `test2`

Comment: @AsafAviv so can't I reuse type?

Comment: You can reuse types. It's hard to understand what you are trying to do, try editing the question and make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you wanted to do, was to put `<A: STRING = STRING>` in function `test` declaration